# How to determine if a point is located inside, outside or on the edge of a complex shape?

Tags: algorithm, image, graphics, 2d, game-development

Provided a complex shape of irregular form, drawn on a 2D surface (let's say a canvas). Provided also a point on that canvas in form of coordinates (e.g. a coordinate of a mouse click).

How to determine if the point resides inside, on the edge or outside of the said object.

For simplicity, let's consider the edge to be one pixel (point) wide.

To facilitate the question and suggest the level of complexity, let's consider a shape as shown on the image below.

[image]

So, to sum up:

1. Is the point with given coordinates inside the shape?
2. Is it on the edge?
3. Or is it outside of the shape?

Answer (score 3):

One possible strategy:

1. Flood-fill the exterior to some color, say red.
2. Any black pixel touching a red pixel is an external border pixel.
3. Any black pixel touching a white pixel is an internal border pixel.
4. All other black pixels are interior to the object.

Points 2–4 can be evaluated concurrently in a single scan of the image.

If you want to do this really fast, you can use OpenGL with an evaluative fragment shader. But that's a bit more involved.

Answer (score 1):

In matlab

```
l = bwlabel( img, 4 ); % label white regions using 4-connect neighbors
[or oc] = find( (l == 0) & imdilate( l == 1, strel('disk',1,0) ) ); % outer boundary
[ir ic] = find( (l == 0) & imdilate( l == 2, strel('disk',1,0) ) ); % inner boundary
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted some [flood-fill algorithm](https://github.com/trustdigits) here. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but try to do a pseudo- edge detection by:

```
filter=[0 -1 0 ; -1 4 -1 ; 0 -1 0];
newImage=conv2(yourImage,filter);
```

It suppose to keep only (or mainly) the outer and inner egdes. After that, if you will do yourImage-newImage, you will get the inside pixels of the abject that are not edges.

I think it can make some of the the work, to further you to the solution.